# BLE read adverts every 0.5 seconds

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have Laird BL6000 BLE device which I have connected with a sensor and configured to advertise data every 0.5 seconds.

Now I want to read this advertising data every 0.5 seconds.

I can read the data using `startScanning()` and access it data in `uiOnLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)` but this process takes about 2-3 seconds. I need to read this data faster than that.

If they have a minimum advertising time 0.5 seconds then there must be a method to read this data.

Comment: That is not an application for scanning - you should connect to the peripheral.  If you want scanning, you will need to advertise much more often than you expect to receive, as it is not a coordinated or reliable operation, but even then you are unlikely to achieve your goal, especially when you start using different phones.

Comment: When I connect to the peripheral, the BLE device stops advertising the data, hence only one connected device will be able to read the data.

Comment: That is what I mentioned in my question, scanning takes to long, I don't want scanning, I only want to read the advertising data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `LeScanCallback` to display the advertising packets?

`onLeScan` method you should receive the packets almost instantly. If you don't maybe your device is not advertising at the period you set.

Try printing a log with the `scanRecord` from the advertising packets you receive:

```
 private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
        Log.i("ON LE SCAN", "UUID: "+ byteArrayToHex(scanRecord));
    }
 };
```

You can also find [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100836/android-listing-ble-devices-after-device-scan/23102124#23102124) a full example on how to scan BLE devices and connect to them.

Good luck!