# Is there a system action to discover and pair Bluetooth devices in Android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

The discovery and pairing process described in the [Android Bluetooth Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices) is quite complex. Even a separate permission is needed for that: `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`.

I wonder if there is a system action, that I just would call, that will handle the UI, return, and the I will just choose an already paired device. Or do I have to implement all that UI myself?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23102124/1549219

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the list of paired bluetooth devices you can use this code

```
public class DeviceList extends ActionBarActivity
{
//widgets
   Button btnPaired;
   ListView devicelist;
//Bluetooth
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

    //Calling widgets
    btnPaired = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //if the device has bluetooth
    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(myBluetooth == null)
    {
        //Show a mensag. that the device has no bluetooth adapter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Device Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //finish apk
        finish();
    }
    else if(!myBluetooth.isEnabled())
    {
            //Ask to the user turn the bluetooth on
            Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnBTon,1);
    }

    btnPaired.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            pairedDevicesList();
        }
    });

}

private void pairedDevicesList()
{
    pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    if (pairedDevices.size()>0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        {
            list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress()); //Get the device's name and the address
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
    devicelist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener); //Method called when the device from the list is clicked

}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        // Get the device MAC address, the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        // Make an intent to start next activity.
        Intent i = new Intent(DeviceList.this, NextActivity.class);

        //Change the activity.
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address); //this will be received at NextActivity
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: This is just choosing one of already paired devices. I meant a dialog to scan for devices and do pairing.